# Распределить пиксели по прямому отрезку

Tags: алгоритм

Есть какой-нибудь прямой отрезок нечётной длины, например, 15px. Как равномерно распределить по нему некоторое количество пикселей таким образом, чтобы соблюдалась симметрия и точки распределялись вплоть до краёв?

Например, как здесь:

```
#   #     #   #
```

Или здесь:

```
# #   # #   # #
```

Comment: Вообще-то у отрезка нет диаметра :) Распределите пиксели равномерно, с округлением координат до ближайшего целого.

Comment: А есть ли для этого алгоритм?

Comment: Как раз таки я знаю, что это. Мне нужно именно по пикселям, т-е, которые имеют только целые значения.

Comment: Округление тоже знаете? Тогда больше ничего и не нужно. Конкретный код — зависит от языка.

Comment: Да, но я чувствую, что при округлении до ближайшего последний пиксель также не достигнет конца отрезка, что и при обычном округлении.

Comment: @Harry условие симметрии делает задачку чуть сложнее, чем вы (и MBo) хотите её представить.

Comment: @Kromster OK, дайте конкретные значения, где это все не сработает, буду смотреть и думать... Кстати (это уже автору вопроса), *чувствую* — это не значит, что так и есть. Есть конкретные значения, когда это не сработает - давайте разбираться...

Comment: В принципе, есть одна неприятная ситуация — четная длина, нечетное количество точек. Но тут, pls, покажите правильное с вашей точки зрения размещение — например, длина 8, 3 точки. Такое решение существует? Если да, то как оно выглядит?

Answer (score 2):

Алгоритм простой.

```
X[i] = Round(i*D/(N-1))

D = 19
N = 4
for i in range(N):
    print(round(i*D / (N-1)))

0
6
13
19
```

Если покажется не совсем симметрично, то вторую половину можно генерировать как отражение первой

Comment: а для не наклонных есть?

Comment: Это для любых..

Comment: Что здесь i вообще значит?

Comment: Номер точки....

Comment: При достижении 4 (если указан диаметр в 15px), i превышает этот самый диаметр

Comment: @Griesur длина линий не называется диаметром. Она называется просто длиной )

Answer (score 0):

Считаем, что тебе нужно расположить точки на одинаковом расстоянии.

Вопрос разбиваем на два:

1. Найти длину (расстояние) между результирующими точками. Это будет длина отрезка поделенная на N-1 (к примеру **для трех точек** 17px/2 = 8.5px, округлять тут не нужно!).
2. Найти угол нашего отрезка; от первой точки отрезка под нужным углом "откладываем" расстояние 8.5px (запоминаем координаты как дробное число) и ставим точку (вот тут можно округлять). От последней запомненной координаты двигаемся нужное число раз.

Можно проще: dX/(N-1) и dY/(N-1) - это будет наш шаг по X и Y (который может быть и отрицательным), а дальше как пункт 2.

Если требуется именно симметрия и разный шаг, то идем зеркально - какое расстояние от первой точки, такое же расстояние откладываем от последней точки (только знак меняем).